# How to format number_to_phone for another country in Rails 4?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, formatting

I'm having some issues with number formatting in rails.

I tried some suggestions from the community when working with string formatting and also the documentation resources:

http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_phone

The thing I tried were these:

```
<%= number_to_phone(client.phone, {:groupings => [4,3,3], delimiter: "-"}) %>
```

and

```
<%= number_to_phone(client.phone, pattern: /(\d{2})(\d{5})(\d{5})$/)) %>
```

None of these turned out to work for me even though the documentations states:

> Formats a number into a phone number (US by default e.g., (555) 123-9876). You can customize the format in the options hash.

and the example provided is:

```
number_to_phone(13312345678, pattern: /(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d{4})$/))
```

=> "133-1234-5678"

I want to format it like this:

> (12)-3456-7890

What am I missing so this code works the way I expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always write your own helper method if you want to:

```
def num_to_phone(num)
  "(#{ num[0..1] })-#{ num[2..5] }-#{ num[6..-1] }"
end
```

Comment: This solved my issue. Marking as answered and upvoted, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The `:pattern` option has been only [added to Rails 5.0.0 rc1](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/4e977da541307dd650917b49e9410a3ca753a944). It won't work in Rails 4. So I guess you are out of luck unless you update to Rails 5.

Comment: This clarified why `pattern:` was not working, thank you.